# Same model in more than one table

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a class, suppose it's called `EntityModel`, and I want to make three different tables with the same columns, as defined in `EntityModel`. Let's call the tables `tbPast`, `tbPresent` and `tbFuture`. I want also to access them separetely in the Entity `DbContext`:

```
using (var db = new MyContext())
{
    var element = db.Past.Find(id);
    db.Past.Remove(element);
    db.Present.Add(element);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

The main purpose of having three tables is performance: the table will have millions of rows, and the most important is the `Present`, with dozens of rows. Most queries will be made in the `Present` table.

What is the best way to do this? Implementing three models with the same properties doesn't seem right for me.

I'm using Entity Framework, with the Code First approach, along with ASP.NET MVC 3.

Comment: In EF world same entity type can not be mapped to different tables. For many reasons. For your purpose I'd use @Teoman Soygul answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the same model to generate separate tables w/ EF code-first. If you need to have some sort of grouping, use a `Discriminator` field and assing it any of the values: `Past` `Present` `Future`.

**Edit:**

Similar effect can be achieved through [table-per-concrete type](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/01/03/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-3-table-per-concrete-type-tpc-and-choosing-strategy-guidelines.aspx) inheritance. Thus each type will have it's own table and can share most (if not all) of the fields.

Comment: `Discriminator` being a regular `string` property? The purpose of separating tables is that most of the queries will be in the `Present` table (there are millions of rows, and the most important is the `Present` with about dozens of rows). What are the performance issues if I use a `Discriminator`?

Comment: A `string` an `int` anything that suits you. If you're so concerned about the performance, see the edit.

Comment: I'll implement the `Discriminator` and measure the performance - if it's not acceptable I'll try the TPC inheritance. Nice link, by the way!